# Nginx proxy_set_header base on verb

Tags: nginx

I have a buggy client which sends a bad `Content-Type` header when POSTing to a specific url. The API in question already sits behind an nginx 1.15 reverse proxy, so as a workaround until those clients can be patched, I'd like to just rewrite the `Content-Type` header for those requests.  I naively tried to set it up like this:

```
location /api/file {
    if ($request_method = POST ) {
      proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/octet-stream";
    }
    proxy_pass http://<api server>/api/file;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
"proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here
```

The same `/api/file` endpoint also supports GET and HEAD methods, which I'd prefer to leave alone. How can I configure this to only apply the `proxy_set_header` to POST requests?

**Update**

For now I've just removed the `if` block entirely and blanket applied the header. Sending `Content-Type` on a GET or HEAD makes no sense, but my API server ignores it in those cases, and this is already a hack anyway.

Comment: You could use `map` directive

Comment: @AlexeyTen do you have any examples of using `map` for something like this? I'm not clear how I would apply it here.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `map` directive.

```
map $request_method $content_type_header {
  default $http_content_type;
  "POST"  "application/octet_stream";
}

server {
  ...
  location /api/file {
    proxy_pass http://server/api/file;
    proxy_set_header Content-Type $content_type_header;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing against the official recommendation. [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/):

> Directive if has problems when used in location context, in some cases
>   it doesn’t do what you expect but something completely different
>   instead. In some cases it even segfaults. It’s generally a good idea
>   to avoid it if possible.
>
> Looks like the only correct fix would be to disable non-rewrite
>   directives inside if completely. It would break many configuration out
>   there though, so wasn’t done yet.

You may use it if you understand how it works and do proper testing. A blog post [How nginx "location if" works](http://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html?m=1) may become handy as it investigates this logic further:

> In short, Nginx's "if" block effectively creates a (nested) location
>   block and once the "if" condition matches, only the content handler of
>   the inner location block (i.e., the "if" block) will be executed.

The error `"proxy_set_header" directive is not allowed here` is probably caused by the nested location block that doesn't anymore have the `proxy_pass` directive in it.

You could imagine that everything outside your `if` was inside an `else`. I'd first try to add it back like this:

```
location /api/file {
    if ($request_method = POST ) {
      proxy_pass http://<api server>/api/file;
      proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/octet-stream";
    }
    proxy_pass http://<api server>/api/file;
}
```

But you need to do the crucial part: testing.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work: `"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement`.

Comment: You can use regular expressions with proxy_pass in a location, the way to do it is use a set directive to set a custom variable to the full url you want to proxy to and use that in your proxy_pass directive